# How to install APCu on Xampp for Linux

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to install APCu on my xampp environment and i'm using ubuntu 16.04 OS.

I have a different php7.0 installation separate from my XAMPP installation, i also followed this guide(https://guides.wp-bullet.com/install-apcu-object-cache-for-php7-for-wordpress-ubuntu-16-04/) and installed APCu successfully but it seems it's not detected by XAMPP

Please how can i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by:

- Re-installing LAMP stack using tasksel
- Running `$ sudo apt-get install php-apcu`

This fixed the issue :)

I'd recommend installing LAMP over XAMPP on a linux OS.